# What are my language choices for making a MacOS daemon?

Tags: java, objective-c, macos, mono

I am a Windows developer (with some iOS Objective-C experience) and I am trying very carefully to choose the correct language to make a fairly simple daemon for the MacOS.

The app will download and upload files, communicating with our .NET web services that are already in place.

The installation will be done by non-technical everyday users, so asking them to do a lot of configuration/scripting on their end is not an option. A sleak package is a requirement.

I see my choices as:

1. Objective-C
2. Java
3. Mono
4. Scripting

**Objective-C** has the advantage that it is native, but I'm not the strongest with this language yet.

**Java** is very easy, but do all users have it? Is it going to be a problem asking people to install it?

**Mono** will let me leverage my .NET skills, but will it install elegantly as a daemon?

**Scripting** may be an option as it is very simple what the app has to do, but is this the norm, to deliver a product like this?

--

**EDIT**

There will be no GUI. I'm okay with not hiding the code, although a UID/PWD will be necessary in order to access the webservices (different for each client). It will always be running, for all clients.

Comment: Will this be a faceless background daemon (so no GUI at all) or are you thinking of something like a Menu Extra that the user will have some control over? Will it be always running for all users or within the context of a single user's login session? How secret do you want to keep the daemon's code (that might rule out a scripting language)? And what options are you considering for installation method (Installer `.pkg` file, Application that will install itself upon first run, drag & drop, etc.)?

Comment: another choice that you didn't list there was plain old C or C++, and you can call into MacOS functions using the Core Foundation framework and API's.

Comment: Have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objective-C/Cocoa or C (esp. using [Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/CFDesignConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000122i)) would certainly give you the most native implementation with performance and OS integration benefits.

Java is reasonable and will be built-in. You'll need some basic scripts to bootstrap it, but not much.

Mono is also reasonable and can be relatively easily installed by the user. You'll need to point them at the download page and specify that they only need the runtime, but it's do-able. Depending on [licensing](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ%3a_Licensing), you may be able to include the Mono runtime installer package within your own installer package so it's installed at the same time as your daemon.

Naturally, scripting languages will most likely leave your code exposed and modifiable, so you may want to avoid that route if that's of concern.

Regardless of the language used to develop the daemon, you'll want to consider installation & management.

For installation, Mac users are used to two installation methods: installing via an Installer `.pkg` file that the user double-clicks and then is brought through the installation process or by dragging an application into their Applications folder and double-clicking to launch. As a developer, the former gives you a lot of control over including README/license text, running pre- & post-flight scripts, building meta packages to install one or more packages (as mentioned above re:possibly including Mono runtimes right in your own installer), and also gives the OS & user the ability to see what files will be installed, where, and when (post-installation) if they so wish. Alternatively, many daemons will be actual Mac OS X applications which will then install themselves as background processes upon the first launch. The former would be independent of your language selection, but the latter would lean towards a Objective-C/Cocoa implementation.

This brings me to management. Most daemons will want to be run through [`launched`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/launchd.8.html) as either a LaunchDaemon (for all users, typically launched at boot) or a LaunchAgent (for particular users, typically launched at login). If you integrate well with `launched` everyone will be happier and should be do-able in any of your language options.

The question then becomes will the user need to manage the daemon at all? If so, this is most frequently implemented as either a MenuExtra or a Preference Pane. In either case, the daemon could be developed in any language and controlled (esp. via `launched`) by the MenuExtra/Preference Pane, but in some cases the MenuExtra could actually function as the daemon and so you'd want to develop in Objective-C/Cocoa.

See also: Apple's [Designing Daemons & Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/DesigningDaemons.html) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

*Objective-C is the best bet*, native, fastest and suitable for a daemon, otherwise you can develop it in Java 6 that is already installed in Mac OS X even though could be not so simple to install it as daemon.

My advice is to go with objective-C or plain C ...

However if you are accustomed to working with .NET you can install mono and use [mono-service](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mono-service) to run the service as a daemon even on OS X, but in this case users will must install mono on their machine, so if you can deal with this trade off could be a viable solutions .